# CreatePartition Help In PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

Can any one give any example of createPartition wmi invocation.
I want to create a GptType partition disk of maximum size.

Comment: I don't want to pass value of Offset and Alignment or by default value is required

Comment: I specially maintained createPartition  method @Avshalom